# jQuery .click doesn't fire when clicking the span tag nested in the a tag

Tags: jquery

I'm using this jQuery to bind a click event to an `<a>` tag

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery(".post-like a").click(function(){

        heart = jQuery(this);

        // Retrieve post ID from data attribute
        post_id = heart.data("post_id");

        // Ajax call
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: ajax_var.url,
            data: "action=post-like&nonce="+ajax_var.nonce+"&post_like=&post_id="+post_id,
            success: function(count){
                // If vote successful
                if(count != "already")
                {
                    heart.addClass("voted");
                    heart.siblings(".count").text(count);
                }
            }
        });

        return false;
    })
})
```

The rendered HTML looks like this

```
<p class="button button_purple ico-like post-like"><a href="#" data-post_id="208" class="likelink"><span class="icon">
<span title="I like this article" class="qtip like"></span></span></a><span class="count">Vote</span></p>
```

The `<span class="count">Vote</span>` is overlapping the a tag and I need to keep the HTML like this. How can I have the jQuery above fire when either the a tag or the span is clicked?

This is the php generating the HTML

```
$output = '<p class="button button_purple ico-like post-like">';
if(hasAlreadyVoted($post_id))
$output .= '<span class="icon"><span title="'.__('I like this article', $themename).'" class="like alreadyvoted"></span></span><span class="count">'.$vote_count.'</span>';
else
$output .= '<a href="#" data-post_id="'.$post_id.'" class="likelink"><span  class="icon">
<span  title="'.__('I like this article', $themename).'" class="qtip like"></span></span></a><span class="count">'."Vote".'</span></p>';
return $output;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.post-like a, .count').click(function(ev){
    var heart;
    if($(ev).is('a')){
        heart = $(this);
    } else {
        heart = $(this).siblings('a');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3LF2y/

Comment: Doesn't this run the function twice? Doesn't it fire the Ajax function twice?

Comment: Assuming that one overlaps the other, no.

Comment: Would you mind showing me how this would look in jsfiddle with my jquery above? I'm not sure how to add the if condition

Comment: This is my jsfiddle, I left the popup there to see if it would fire but it's not http://jsfiddle.net/peter/74pCV/1/

Comment: Where are you setting `ajax_var`? It's undefined, and that's why it isn't working.

Comment: In `functions.php` of the wordpress theme

Comment: Is it a PHP variable or a JS variable?

Answer (score 0):

you could trigger the a-click manually if the span is clicked:

```
jQuery(".post-like .count").click(function(){
    jQuery(this).prev('a').trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: Chrome console gives this error `Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Window] is not a function` on `$(this).prev('a').trigger('click');`

Comment: @Anagio sorry, use jQuery instead in that case

Answer (score 0):

two ways:

put the `span.count` inside the `<a>` element

or

assign the click to the `<p>` element

Comment: When I bind the click event to the `p` the count isn't displayed, something to do with `heart.siblings(".count").text(count);` i'm not familiar with how siblings works. When the `a` is clicked the word Vote is replaced with the quantity of votes `count`. I'm updating my question to display the php

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a .count class for the span you can use it to bind the click event.

```
$(".post-like a,.count").click(function(){
```

Comment: Doesn't this run the function twice? Doesn't it fire the Ajax function twice?

Comment: @srini.venigalla  Not sure.. but it only logs the click once http://jsfiddle.net/NRNT4/